# Web application like DailyBurn with free Android app

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm looking for a DailyBurn.com replacement, because it does not offer data exports and does not have free Android application. I also don't like that their graphs are buggy and use flash. Please, recommend a website that matches these criteria. I want to monitor fat percentage and weight, anything else is a plus.

Comment: +1 for specifying a product that already exists, it's shortcomings for your scenario and the features that you would like to have. This is very helpful when trying to determine another product.